# Write Eloquent queries in raw mysql

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I want to know how can I write These two Eloquent Queries into raw SQL? also Is there a way to convert the Eloquent series into raw SQL series so that I could use those?

```
    public function items()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'order_items', 'order_id', 'product_id')->withPivot('quantity', 'price');
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we talk about the first query used in the `items` method. After changing it into raw SQL it will become

```
DB::select('select `products`.*, `order_items`.`order_id` as `pivot_order_id`, `order_items`.`product_id` as `pivot_product_id`, `order_items`.`quantity` as `pivot_quantity`, `order_items`.`price` as `pivot_price` from `products` inner join `order_items` on `products`.`id` = `order_items`.`product_id` where `order_items`.`order_id` = `order_id`');
```

and the second query inside the `user` method will become

```
DB::select('select * from `users` where `users`.`id` = `id`');
```

Comment: Yes, these queries are really working, Thank you so much. It will help me understand it better.